# reduce a lot of require() function

Tags: javascript, browserify, commonjs

I have a lot of `CommonJS` modules and I need to add all of them to array. Therefore, I have a huge repeated code:

```
//Container module
var module1 = require('module1'),
    module2 = require('module2'),
 ...
    module25 = require('module25')

var container = [];
container.push(module1);
container.push(module2);
...
container.push(module25);

module.exports = container;
```

Is it possible to reduce this code? I don't want to make them globaly. I see only only solution, it's inject `container` inside each module, but I don't want my modules know about `container`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, you wish to export an array of modules and get access to that array, i.e. `require`, somewhere else. If this is correct, you could do something like this:

```
// requires-file
module.exports = [
    require('module1'),
    require('module2'),
    // ...
];
```

Or a more functional programming approach, this would appeal more to me, but people prefer different styles:

```
module.exports = ['module1', 'module2', /*...*/].map(function(m) {return require(m);});
```

And where you need the files, you can use:

```
// other-file
var container = require('/requires-file');
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't solve my problem. I have to write `require` 25 times anyway, in the `requires-file`.

Comment: Well yes, you can't change that, but it's still less than 25 lines of requires and 25 lines of `.push`. Or you could use `fs.readdir` on node_modules and add each installed module to the array, but then there is a problem with adding too much modules and with order of imports. Can you explain what is the use case where you need 25 modules and you need all of them in each file?